# MySQL 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' when getting leaderboard data

Tags: mysql

I have a query that gets a list of games:

```
SELECT 
1+(SELECT count(*) from games a WHERE a.score > g.score) as rank,
score, p.leaderboard_initials, p.operating_system, IF(p.picture_code = 0, p.picture_url, p.picture_code) AS picture_code
FROM games g
inner join players p on (p.google_id = g.google_id)
where p.leaderboard_initials LIKE CONCAT('%', 'db3sq', '%')
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

There are two players with the same leaderboard initials, 'db3sq':

[image]

I need to return, in the case of 'db3sq', two rows, showing the top score for each player.  The following query only gets the first row:

```
set @rank=0;
select (@rank:=@rank+1) rank , max(score)  score, leaderboard_initials, operating_system,  picture_code 
from  (
SELECT 
1+(SELECT count(*) 
from games a WHERE a.score > g.score) as rank,
score, p.leaderboard_initials, p.operating_system, IF(p.picture_code = 0, p.picture_url, p.picture_code) AS picture_code
FROM games g
inner join players p on (p.google_id = g.google_id)
where p.leaderboard_initials LIKE CONCAT('%', 'db3sq', '%')
ORDER BY score DESC
) t  
group by leaderboard_initials 
order by score DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

[image]

When I change the `count(*)` to `count(DISTINCT p.google_id)` I get the error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. I feel I should use `group_concat` somehow.  How can I get the two rows showing the top score for each player?

**EDIT**:  You probably also need to know that `players` has a `primary key` `google_id` that is the `foreign key` in `games`.

Comment: Is it defined a unique key per user or can you CONCAT two fields to create one?

Comment: @DagSondreHansen Edited the question.  Thanks

Comment: I would try creating a dataset using the unique keys (instead of user names). Use this query as the FROM data source and then resolve the user names.

Comment: @DagSondreHansen Right.  That makes sense actually.  On my way to work now but I might try that approach in the evening.  Cheers.